# How to fetch code additions and deletions from Bitbucket API 2

Tags: git, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

In the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit) we have the possibility to get stats from a specific commit.

E.g.:

```
    "stats": {
      "additions": 104,
      "deletions": 4,
      "total": 108
     }
```

I would like to know if for Bitbucket API V2 we have the same feature, I'm currently using:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ZZZ" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/thesithorder/zzz/commit/6530c6c43a0c618321866e0150e119dad00db2d4
```

To get a specific commit but in that answer, I don't have the number of code additions/deletions. Thank you.

Comment: I would also like to know this.